# Setting default orientation of YouTube player

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, embedding

I have read the post http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/display-youtube-videos-without-exiting-your-application.html

And YouTube player runs successfully. But every time I run the video, the YouTube player always plays the video with a landscape orientation.

Is there any way to make it runs with portrait orientation as a default one in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the embed link http://www.youtube.com/embed/-0Xa4bHcJu8.

Comment: Whoa it's what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot, Mate. :)